# Printing three strings with identical content gives different results

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

```
#include "stdio.h"

void main()
{
    char firstName[1] = "1";
    char middleName[1] = "1";
    char lastName[1] = "1";

    printf("%p\t%s\n",firstName,firstName);
    printf("%p\t%s\n",middleName,middleName);
    printf("%p\t%s\n",lastName,lastName);
}
```

I compile this code use the gcc 4.8.2, what is confusing me is why it print:

> >
>   root@ubuntu:~# ./main

```
0x7fff7124273d  111
0x7fff7124273e  11
0x7fff7124273f  1
```

I think it should print:

```
0x7fff7124273d  1
0x7fff7124273e  1
0x7fff7124273f  1
```

Can you help me?

Comment: allocate 2 bytes instead of 1 for the char arrays. You always have to leave 1 additional char for the '\0' string terminator

Comment: Remember that strings should be terminated with `'\0'`.

Comment: You don't have enough space in your arrays for the `\0`

Comment: change to `char firstName[] = "1";`. same for all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because size of array is 1 and you are assigning the array of length 2 (string literal also have null character `\0` at the end). Hence, string pointed by the pointer may not be NULL terminated string. You need array of size 2.

```
char firstName[2] = "1";
char middleName[2] = "1";
char lastName[2] = "1";
```

or

```
char firstName[] = "1";
char middleName[] = "1";
char lastName[] = "1";
```

Also, do not use `void main` in C. Use `int main`.

Answer (score 6):

```
char firstName[1] = "1";
```

It's legal to initialize a `char` array like this, but it's not a string, because it's not null-terminated.

`"%s"` in `printf` expects a string, so what you are doing is undefined behavior.

---

My guess is, the compiler puts the variables together, and what byte after them happens to be `0`, that can explain what happened. But again, it's undefined behavior, anything could happen.

```
     '1'      '1'     '1'      0
     ^         ^       ^
 firstName     |       |
         middleName    |
                    lastName
```

Answer (score 2):

`"1"` is actually two bytes in size - `'1', '\0'` - you're forgetting that C strings are null-terminated. The null bytes are getting trashed by the initialization. Your arrays need to be big enough to contain all the data in the initializer to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, *C-style strings* are *null-terminated* arrays, meaning that there should be `'\0'` after the string. Notes that might help you:

- `char firstName[2] = "1";` - Adds `'\0'` by itself, note the 2 instead of 1.
- `char firstName[] = {'1'}` - Does **not** add `'\0'`.
- `char firstName[2] = {'1'}` - **adds** `'\0'`.

You're getting this output because probably the chars are put together, this is undefined behavior.

Comment: the second and third example is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

in your code

```
printf("%p\t%s\n",firstName,firstName);
```

the first thing getting printed is the base address of the array firstName,

the second thing is actually undefined behaviour. for any character array to be a string it must have null character `\0` at the end. your array is only 1 character long., and containing `'1'`. so you acnnot use `%s` to print that.

instead of %s use %c to print the character, like \

```
printf("%p\t%c\n",firstName,firstName);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, strings are NUL-terminated, i.e. the string "1" is the characters {'1', 0}. You have not allowed enough room for the terminator, so your strings are truncated and printf doesn't know where they end.

It would be better to define them as

```
char firstName[2] = "1";
```

and best to do

```
char firstName[] = "1";
```

so the compiler calculates the right amount of memory for you if you should ever deal with some with a first name which is longer than 1 character.

Comment: Fixed typo. Are you sure about '\0' != (char)0?